# Sprite node won't move when touch is recognized in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, xcode, position, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I am trying to make a sprite node move when the user touches above a certain point on the screen. My touch is being recognized, but no movement is happening!

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    SKSpriteNode *_box = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    _box.position = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);

    [_box addChild:_box];
}
return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    _currentTouch = touch;
}
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
CGPoint currentLocation = [_currentTouch locationInView:_currentTouch.view];
if (currentLocation.y > 300) {
    _box.position = CGPointMake(_box.position.x, _box.position.y + 20);
    NSLog(@"touching");
     }
}

@end
```

I'm not sure if I'm just going about it the wrong way, but I could desperately use some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes in your code so it's easier to show you a sample project which does what you are asking:

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *myNode;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        myNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
        myNode.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        [self addChild:myNode];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

    if(touchLocation.y > 200)
    {
        myNode.position = CGPointMake(myNode.position.x, myNode.position.y+10);
    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly!